# Error trying to connect MongoDB with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb

**Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist**

I am trying to connect to mongoDB with mongoose but I get this error, I don't know what it is, my data such as user, password and database name are correct.

Comment: Can you provide more details? Is your IP allowed to connect to DB (whitelisted)?

Comment: good day friend, I do not know the truth, I am new and I am learning when I create the cluster and my profile in mongodb never asked me for my IP. I am making the connection with mongoose and following the example that mongodb offers me. I already have the data such as username, password, database and uri and with that I am making the connection.